# Центральное значение по оси X

Tags: c#, .net, graph

Есть график (статичный):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить центрально значение по оси Х?
Пример того, как должно выглядеть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Используется библиотека Live Charts (C#)***

Comment: 250 / 2.........

Comment: @codename0082016 вопрос в том, как получить "видимые" значения по оси и уже основываясь на этом я смогу получить центральное значение